# $|Syl_p(G)|$ divides $|Syl_p(H)|$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $f:G\to H$ be an epimorphism of finite groups. Then the cardinality of $Syl_p(G)$ divides the cardinality of $Syl_p(H)$.

($Syl_p(G)$ denotes the set of Sylow p-groups in $G$.)

Using a previous exercise which says $$K\subset G \text{ Sylow p-group } \implies f(K)\subset H \text{ Sylow p-group }$$
we can define a map $Syl_p(G)\to Syl_p(H), K\mapsto f(K)$. I think this map is surjective and I tried to prove it. But even if I prove that, how can we conclude the claim?
Does $Syl_p(G)$ form a group under intersection so that we could apply the isomorphism theorem?

This seems like the wrong approach, but I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: Try using the formula $|{\rm Syl}_p(G) = |G:N_G(P)|$ for $P \in {\rm Syl}_p(G)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One needs a lemma first (I use $N_G(P)$ to denote the normalizer of $P$ in $G$)

> Lemma: If $f:G \to H$ is an epimorphism, then for any subgroup $P< G$, $f(N_G(P)) = N_H(f(P))$

Proof: It is clear that $f(N_G(P)) \subset N_H(f(P))$ simply because $f$ is a homomorphism. Conversely, since $f$ is surjective, $\exists$ a subgroup $K<G$ such that $N_H(f(P)) = f(K)$. In particular, $f(P) \vartriangleleft f(K)$, so $P \vartriangleleft K$ (again, by the correspondence theorem), so $K \subset N_G(P)$, whence $f(K) \subset f(N_G(P))$.

From this, it follows that
$$
N_H(f(P)) \cong \frac{N_G(P)}{N_G(P)\cap\ker(f)}
$$
and so
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
[H:N_H(f(P))] &= \frac{|H||N_G(P)\cap\ker(f)|}{|N_G(P)|} \\
&= \frac{|G||N_G(P)\cap\ker(f)|}{|\ker(f)||N_G(P)|} \\
&= \frac{[G:N_G(P)]}{[\ker(f):N_G(P)\cap\ker(f)]}
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
which is what you need.

Comment: Thank you. But I don't see how you concluded that $[G:N_G(P)] \lvert [H:N_H(f(P))]$.  We have $[H:N_H(f(P))]=[G/\ker f: N_G(P)]$ right? Did you somehow use that?

Comment: @user346022: Have edited the posted.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the edit.